# Need code translation from VB to C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Can someone translate me the following code from VB to C#? As far as I understand it is declaration of a function that calls another function from the native library "user32.dll"...

`Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Integer) As Integer`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setforegroundwindow):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Comment: The [MarshalAs] is unnecessary, that's the default.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a code translation from VB.NET to C# or from C# to VB.NET you can go to http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/, here you can convert from one language to another practically any code you can imagine and type.

Comment: Any code you can imagine EXCEPT the line of code in the original post. That throws an error :)