# convert classic ASP to ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp-classic

```
<%
       Dim xmlDoc; 
Dim objNodeList;
Dim count;

set xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");

xmlDoc.validateOnParse = False;
xmlDoc.async = False;

xmlDoc.loadXML("<div>" & Request.Form("inTransContent")   & "</div>");

Else
      Set objNodeList = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("//text()");
      count = objNodeList.length;

      For i = 1 To count 
           objNodeList(i-1).insertData 0, "XYZ " ;
           objNodeList(i-1).insertData objNodeList(i-1).length, " XYZ" ;
      Next 

      Response.Write(xmlDoc.documentElement.xml);
End If

%>
```

Hi, I need to convert this code to `C#` and I'm not that familiar with vbscript!!

Kindly can anyone convert this code!!

Thanks

Comment: The VBScript code is incomplete, so it's not possible to make a meaningful conversion.

Comment: but if you familiar with c# code, then it should be a piece of cake to translate from vbscript to c#?

Comment: This is not plain `VBScript` it's server side classic ASP code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Look here!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502414/need-code-translation-from-vb-to-c) (An SO question asking how to call native routines from managed)

[And here!!!](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) (An online utility for converting between different .NET languages)

Answer (score 1):

One of the wonderful things in `.NET` is that you can write it using different languages.

One of those is `VB.NET` that should be backward compatible enough to support your code, and even if not then converting classic ASP to `VB.NET` should be easy as the syntax is the same.

So just change the project to `VB.NET` instead of `C#` and you're good to go.